# How to know an app's target sdk version

Tags: android, sdk, apk

I'm doing some android analysis and need to find all the android app that have targetSdkversion over 23, right now I'm reverse engineering all the apk packages to see this...Wondering if there's more easy way to get this information given an app name?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by this code:

```
int sdkVersion = 0;

IPackageManager packageManager = AppGlobals.getPackageManager();

try {

    ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(yourAppName, 0);

    if (applInfo != null) {

        sdkVersion = applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to android development though, I just mean that I want to know an app's target sdk version given the docid of it. (don't necessarily have the apk file) Thank you